# never ending syntax error in sql + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Frequency', 'Cache', 'L2 Cache', 'L3 Cache', 'Cores', 'TDP', 'Voltage', 'Socket' at line 1

```
INSERT INTO cpu ('Frequency', 'Cache', 'L2 Cache', 'L3 Cache', 'Cores', 'TDP', 'Voltage', 'Socket', 'Threads', 'CoreName', 'Brand', 'Architecture', 'ModelName', 'Series', 'bitSupport', 'manufacturingTechnology', 'DMI', 'HyperTransport', 'picture', 'description') VALUES ('df', 'asdff', '', '', 'asdfsadf', '', 'werwr', 'wfwef', '', 'asdf', 'asdgasdf', 'asderg', 'asdfasdf', '', '', 'asdfasdf', '', '', '', '', )
```

have problem with this query, it just cannot be accepted by database and i have no idea why

Comment: either remove the single qoutes `'` around column names or use backticks `\``

Comment: and there is a trailing , in the argument list

Answer (score 3):

Column names are enclosed in backticks ` not in single quotes '